# Storing MSAL Graph API token in client side React and reusing it until expiry

Tags: javascript, reactjs, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I am fairly new to React. This question is related to storing the authentication token in the client side and reusing it until expiry.

I am using MSAL to for authentication in my React app. Below is my code.

```
import * as React from 'react';

import {AuthOptions, CacheOptions, SystemOptions} from './MsalConfig';
import { UserAgentApplication } from 'msal';

//export const authContext: AuthenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(msalConfig);

export const msalInstance = new UserAgentApplication({
  auth: AuthOptions,
  cache: CacheOptions,
  system: SystemOptions
});

export const withAuth = function(WrappedComponent){
  return class Auth extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        authenticated: false,
        renewIframe: false,
        hasError: false,
        errorMessage: null,
        graphAPIToken: null
      };
    }

    componentWillMount() {
      this.checkAuthentication();
    }

    checkAuthentication = () => {
      if(this.state.graphAPIToken == null){
        // action to perform on authentication
        msalInstance.handleRedirectCallback(() => { // on success
          this.setState({
            authenticated: true
          });
        }, (authErr, accountState) => {  // on fail
          console.log("Error after graph API call " + authErr);

          this.setState({
            hasError: true,
            errorMessage: authErr.errorMessage
          });
        });

        // if we are inside renewal callback (hash contains access token), do nothing
        if (msalInstance.isCallback(window.location.hash)) {
          this.setState({
            renewIframe: true
          });
          return;
        }

        // not logged in, perform full page redirect
        if (!msalInstance.getAccount()) {
          msalInstance.loginRedirect({});
          return;
        } else {     // logged in, set authenticated state
          this.setState({
            authenticated: true
          }, () => {
            this.getAccessToken(msalInstance);
          });
        }
      }
    }

    getAccessToken = (msalInstance) => {
      console.log(msalInstance);
      // if the user is already logged in you can acquire a token
      if (msalInstance.getAccount()) {
          var tokenRequest = {
              scopes: ["user.read"]
          };
          msalInstance.acquireTokenSilent(tokenRequest)
              .then(response => {
                  // get access token from response
                  // response.accessToken
                  console.log(response.accessToken);
                  this.setState({
                    graphAPIToken: response.accessToken
                  });
                  //return response.accessToken;
              })
              .catch(err => {
                  // could also check if err instance of InteractionRequiredAuthError if you can import the class.
                  if (err.name === "InteractionRequiredAuthError") {
                      return msalInstance.acquireTokenPopup(tokenRequest)
                          .then(response => {
                              // get access token from response
                              // response.accessToken
                              console.log(response.accessToken);
                              this.setState({
                                graphAPIToken: response.accessToken
                              });
                              //return response.accessToken;
                          })
                          .catch(err => {
                              console.log("Error inside getAccessToken " + err);
                          });
                  }
                  console.log("Error inside getAccessToken " + err);
              });
      } else {
          // user is not logged in, you will need to log them in to acquire a token
          console.log("u aren't logged in");
      }
  }

  callGraphAPI = (token) => {
      //..
  }

    render(){
      if (this.state.renewIframe) {
        return <div>hidden renew iframe - not visible</div>;
      }

      if (this.state.authenticated) {
        return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />;
      }

      if (this.state.hasError) {
        console.log("Login error: " + this.state.errorMessage);
      }

      console.log("Login error: " + this.state.errorMessage);
    }
  };
}
```

Now, I am using this in my React routes in my `index.js`:

```
ReactDOM.render(<MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <Router>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/" exact component={(withAuth)(Projects)}/>
                <Route path="/signin" exact component={SignIn}/>
                <Route path="/projects" exact component={(withAuth)(Projects)}/>
                <Route path="/admin" exact component={(withAuth)(Admin)}/>
                <Route path="/projectstages/:projectNumber" exact component={(withAuth)(ProjectStages)}/>
                <Route path="/formspage" exact component={(withAuth)(FormsPage)}/>
                <Route path="/users" exact component={(withAuth)(UserManagement)}/>
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    </MuiThemeProvider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Whenever I access any URL, the `componentWillMount` of `withAuth` component will get called to check the authentication. How do I make sure that the token is generated only once and stored in the cache and reuse it until it expires? Also, I am not sure if I have implemented the authentication in correct way. Any help with this please?

Comment: When your component mounts, you should try to acquire a token silently from MSAL. Then if that fails, interactive authentication may be needed.

Comment: @juunas I am fetching the token in during mount of `withAuth` component. Problem is with every URL request or refresh, the mount will make a call to fetch token. Without redux, how do I reuse the existing token?

Comment: If you call acquireTokenSilent on MSAL, it should return you the cached token even after a refresh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to worry about caching the token and renewing it, MSAL does this all for you.

(In fact, I recommend you specifically *do not* do your own token caching if you're using MSAL. You risk accidentally introducing your own security vulnerability.)

As described in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-spa-acquire-token), every time you want to make an API request, you should call `acquireTokenSilent`. One of three situations will happen:

1. If MSAL has an existing token in it's own cache that matches the parameters you give it, MSAL will provide the token right away.
2. If a token refresh is needed (e.g. because the cached access token is expired, or because you need an access token for a different API), MSAL will attempt to do a silent token refresh. If this succeeds silently, MSAL provides the fresh access token.
3. If MSAL doesn't have a cached valid access token, and MSAL can't silently refresh it (e.g. the user has not signed in,  they've signed out, or the user needs to consent to a new permission), then MSAL will let you know and you can handle that situation as needed (e.g. use `acquireTokenPopup` to use a popup, or `acquireTokenRedirect` to use a redirect).